# TF401019 :Git failed with a fatal error. repository 'https://aitsg.visualstudio.com/_git/CelebrityStyleAdmin/' not found

Tags: azure-devops

I have no idea why i cannot clone the repository with the screenshot?
I just normal user, is that my admin control that right?

Please provide instruction step by step to solve this issue.

This 2 thread can't solve the problem
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b8bc2526-a7ba-470c-9b4f-1d98c3e98ee9/tf401019-the-git-repository-with-name-or-does-not-exist?forum=tfsversioncontrol
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0c0f6097-7c67-4d73-ad32-6d2b9205020e/unable-to-perform-any-actions-clone-sync-push-etc-tofrom-a-vsts-git-repo-in-vs2017?forum=tfsversioncontrol

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmK0g.png)

Comment: Can you access to the web page `https://aitsg.visualstudio.com/_git/CelebrityStyleAdmin/`?

Comment: yes...problem already solve..my manager set wrong access level to me.